# How do I get census data of a particular zip code?

Tags: api, census

```
https://api.census.gov/data/2013/acs/acs5?get=NAME,B01001_001E&for=place:51000&in=state:36&key=key123
```

That is the query I attempted to use. I only get the data for New York City population, but I want the population of that zip code, and if possible query further onto the data of that zip code. I obtained the "place" using ZTCA5 to place chart they provided.
thanks.